# Setting dates on x-axis with ggplot2

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis

I've gone through all similar questions, but still I struggle to find a solution to my problem.

I have this code:

```
finl <- as.data.frame(cbind(plus,centre,minus,indx))
head(finl)

> head(finl)
     plus    centre     minus indx
1 0.5202951 0.3699147 0.2195342    1
2 0.5328857 0.3890009 0.2451162    2
3 0.5421306 0.3979195 0.2537085    3
4 0.6421294 0.5154826 0.3888357    4
5 0.7312431 0.6132432 0.4952434    5
6 0.7325199 0.6089201 0.4853203    6


ggplot(finl) +
geom_line(aes(indx,centre), group = 1) +
geom_ribbon(aes(x = indx, ymax = plus , ymin = minus), alpha = 0.6, fill = "skyblue") +
ggtitle("Movement over time")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face = "bold")) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
    axis.title = element_text(size=14))+
labs(x="Period", y="Y-value")
```

And here is the graph - [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/redSz.jpg)

Also I have variable **date**:

```
date <- ldate[-c(length(ldate))]
date <- as.Date(date)
head(date)

> head(date)
[1] "2008-11-28" "2008-12-31" "2009-01-30" "2009-02-27" "2009-03-31" "2009-04-30"
```

My question is how to put these dates as an x-axis on my graph?

I've tried with **scale_x_date**, but somehow I am not able to solve this problem and to get appropriate graph. I get some strange results.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: bind `date` to the dataframe and use it as `x` in aes

Comment: Thanks! But now only four years are on the axis. Do you know how to put all years (from 2008 to 2016) on the axis instead only some of them?

Comment: if you only want years: `date <- seq(2008, 2016)` but maybe you want to use a time series library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First insert the dates into the `dataframe`:

```
finl<-cbind(finl,date)
```

Then replace `indx` with the `date` column of `finl` in your `ggplot` code